Calculate the volume of the stairs

Jack want to build a stairs which has 20 steps created by 20 prisms like the image. The top is the $A_1B_1C_1.A_1'B_1'C_1'$ prism has $A_1B_1 =3, B_1C_1 = 2, A_1A_1' = 2$ units and $\widehat{A_1B_1C_1}= 90 ^o$. On the other hand: $$B_{i+1}C_{i+1} = B_iC_i + 1$$$$\widehat{A_{i+1}B_{i+1}C_{i+1}} = \widehat{A_iB_iC_i} + 3^o$$
$$A_{i+1}A_{i+1}'=A_iA_i' + 0.1$$
Moreover, all the face $B_iC_iC_i'B_i'$ stay on the same plane, and $A_{i+1}B_{i+1} = A_iC_i$; and $B_{i+1} \equiv B_i$.
Calculate the volume of the stairs?
Here is what I got so far:
Let $a_n = B_nC_n$, $b_n = A_nC_n$, and $c_n = \widehat{A_nB_nC_n}$
Therefore,
$$a_n = a_{n-1}+1$$
$$b_n = b_{n-1} + 0.1$$
$$c_n = c_{n-1} + 3^o$$
And the volume of the prism $A_nB_nC_n.A_n'B_n'C_n'$
is:
$$A_nA_n'.S_{\triangle A_nB_nC_n} = \dfrac{1}{2}A_nB_n.A_nC_n.A_nA_n'.\sin A_nB_nC_n$$
But the next step require 3 sequences and complex steps
Can anyone help me with an easy solution please so I can make a generalization about this problem to $n$ prism, thank you.

A question of style. "Jack want(s) to build stairs..." is the text of your Homework. Addressing the question to us, grown up people, you can just begin instead by "The objective is to build stairs..."
